# Prove $\rho(A) \le \|A\|$

Tags: proof-writing, normed-spaces, proof-explanation

Here is the question:

> **$4.13$** Prove that for any matrix norm induced by a vector norm, $\rho(a)\le||A||.$

$\rho(A) $ is $spectral$ $radius$ of $A$

I have no idea how to even begin doing something here.

I looked for something related to this and the closest thing that I found was: http://people.math.gatech.edu/~meyer/MA6701/module11a.pdf which proves that a matrix A induced by the infinity norm is equal to its maximum row sum, which I don't think is the same thing as my question.

Comment: You haven't said what $\rho(A)$ is.

Comment: Is $\rho(A)$ supposed to be the spectral radius of $A$?

Comment: Yes, it is spectral radius

Comment: It is best avoid the use of pictures for critical portions of a post. Pictures
cannot be searched and are inaccessible to those using screen readers.

Comment: Your last edit was simply to remove the problem you want help with from the body of the Question, making it incoherent.  I have reverted the edit.

Answer (score 2):

If $Av = \lambda v$ for some unit $v$, then $\|A\| \ge \|Av\| = |\lambda| $. Hence $\|A\| \ge \rho(A)$.

Comment: Is this the proof?

Comment: It is the essence of the proof. Look at the definition of $\rho$. The only other step is the use of the induced norm. If you don't understand, then ask more specific questions.

Comment: You think you can give me some jargon or pseudo-math to complement this. I feel that even though the answer is elegant and simple, the person reviewing my paper is going to complain because of the length. Thanks for the response

Comment: You will have to do that yourself. If you have a problem with the mathematics I can assist.